# Mirror HTML's CSS Attr To Codemirror (insert new line)

Tags: javascript, jquery

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Mukdf/

Today I decided to mirror an html's css attr to Codemirror to see if it can render out clean CSS rather than all on one line.

Here's the css that's being mirrored to Codemirror...

```
display: inherit; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 19px; margin: 10px; width: 340px; height: 234px; padding: 1em; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: arial; line-height: normal; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px dashed rgb(0, 255, 255); border-top-left-radius: 0em; border-top-right-radius: 0em; border-bottom-right-radius: 0em; border-bottom-left-radius: 0em; background-color: rgb(0, 34, 102); text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 0px 8px; overflow: visible; z-index: 0;
```

I'm trying to get it displayed like this...

```
display: inherit; 
position: absolute; 
top: 20px; 
left: 19px; 
margin: 10px; 
width: 340px; 
height: 234px; 
padding: 1em; 
font-style: normal; 
font-variant: normal; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-size: 14px; 
font-family: arial; 
line-height: normal; 
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
border: 0px dashed rgb(0, 255, 255); 
border-top-left-radius: 0em; 
border-top-right-radius: 0em; 
border-bottom-right-radius: 0em; 
border-bottom-left-radius: 0em; 
background-color: rgb(0, 34, 102); 
text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 0px 8px; 
overflow: visible; 
z-index: 0;
```

I know this is possible I just don't know how to go about it. I want to find `;` and replace that with the same character but add a line break at the end.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my JQuery/JS...

```
$('.div-style').val($('.box').attr('style'));

$('.code').each(function() {
    CodeMirror(this, {
        value: $('.div-style').val(),
        mode: 'text/css',
        lineNumbers: true,
        lineWrapping: true,
        readOnly: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global replace to change all semicolons to a semicolon followed by a newline would be:

```
$('.div-style').val().replace(/;/g,";\n")
```

Though you'll notice that leaves a space at the beginning of all lines but the first because your input has a space after each semicolon: http://jsfiddle.net/Mukdf/1/

So perhaps this:

```
$('.div-style').val().replace(/;\s?/g,";\n")
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mukdf/2/

Or `/;\s*/g` if you want to allow for any number of spaces (including zero) after each semicolon.

Comment: So is \g like a global modifier to replace all copies of that matched string? (I know \t is tab \n is new line which is why I'm wondering about \g)

Comment: Yes, without `g` it will just replace the first one. Note that it's not `\g` with a backslash, it's just `g` as a flag after the closing `/` (forward slash) of the actual expression. The expression you're matching on is the bit between the forward slashes, and any flags come after the second `/`. (There are a few other flags you can specify, e.g., `i` for "ignore case".)